# SQLite DB from Android to WP 7-8

Tags: android, windows-phone-7.1, windows-phone, windows-phone-8

I'm trying to develop a simple app cross platform which use a SQLite db.
Actually I have an Android app which use this db and I'm looking for a good solution to use this DB in other app based on WP 7-8 and W8 OS.

I read this guid http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/news/windows-phone-7-native-database-programming-via-sqlite-client-for-wp7
but at the same time I found the Precompiled Binaries for Windows Phone 8 on  http://www.sqlite.org/download.html

Now I'm just a little bit confused and I don't understand two things:

- is WPGeek's solution usefull also for WP8? or now, thanks to WP8 and
  W8 everything is changed?
- Can I use the precompiled binaries for WP8 to create an app for WP
  7.1?

Are there other solutions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AFAIK, WPGeek's solution is useful for WP8 as well. You cannot use the WP8's binaries for WP 7 now. So, if you are targeting both 7.1 and 8, better go with the WPGeeks solution.

And the process is a bit different for Windows 8 again. You can take the advantage of the Precompiled binaries there.

Answer (score 1):

For both WP7.1 and WP8 I use 
 http://sqlitewindowsphone.codeplex.com/releases it works good for me